# @validate deocrator of sanic-ext with pydantic model with extra=ignore param passing

Tags: python-3.x, pydantic, sanic

I am using pydantic 1.9.0 and passing extra=Extra.ignore
but when I'm validating my request using sanic-ext's validate decorator. It is not allowing me to pass extra params.
attaching sanic doc link https://sanic.dev/en/plugins/sanic-ext/validation.md#decorators

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Extra
from sanic import Sanic, response
from sanic_ext import validate


# Pydantic model for query parameters
class QueryParamsModel(BaseModel, extra=Extra.ignore):
    name: str
    age: int


app = Sanic(__name__)


@app.get('/user')
@validate(query=QueryParamsModel)
async def get_user(request, query):
    return response.json({'message': f"name: {query.name}"})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```